# Eclipse RCP - advantage of Forms

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I just want to know what is the need/use of Eclipse forms?, when we can created the SWT controls by our self in a composite.

Thanks & Regards,
Chinna

Comment: Look at something like the plugin.xml editor - that is a FormEditor. It is much easier to structure the code for this cleanly using things like FormPages and Sections than it would be with just JFace/SWT.

Answer (score 0):

This is a citation from [Eclipse Forms: Rich UI for the Rich Client](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Forms/article.html)

> Spice up your rich client with rich user experience using Eclipse Forms.

It is build upon SWT/JFace and has some nice functionality.